# Touchcreen on Windows 7 Embedded

Tags: windows-7, touchscreen

I have one of these MPI7001 7inch capacitive touchscreen device. This is documented in [this link here](http://www.lcdwiki.com/7inch_HDMI_Display-B).

I got it to work (display and touch) on Raspbian. However I need this to run on my windows 7 Embedded device. Display works ok but touch does not work at all.

I tried various thing and also looked for the "pen and touch" settings in the control panel. However this is not even available in windows 7 embedded.

Any help you could give me? Where to look?

###Edit###
When plugging the monitor on Linux and issuing lsbusb the device is reported as
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0483:5750 STMicroelectronics

Comment: I've used Win7 Embedded on POS platforms before, so I am pretty sure touchscreen drivers at least exist. The screen doc says, "Connect the LCD's USB Touch interface (Either of the two MicroUSB) to the USB port of the device". Ensure you have this additional USB cable connected. Also look in Device Manager after connecting the USB cable to see what kind of driver it is using.

Comment: Thanks Jim. Yes all cables connected. I got this far obviously. Device manager showed a missing driver in usb interfaces and no way to make it auto download anything.

Comment: You'll need to manually find an appropriate driver for that missing device. You could edit your post and include details about the missing device driver if you wanted some help trying to find it. Often the manufacturer will have something available on their website. I did a little digging, and found "CFSunbird" as a manufacturer on Alibaba website. Using this Google query, cfsunbird touchscreen driver windows 10 -alibaba -amazon, I found "Microsoft Touch Pack for Windows 7" which may help. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17368

Comment: Thank you. I came across this link at the beginning but it's not the right one. I'll double check if this is a CFSunbird. To me it looks I bought something that has been developed for Raspberrypi only and there might be no driver yet for Windows. I really wish I did not need a windows machine but have no choice.

Comment: Did you customize the Windows on your own or did you buy it ?  Win7 Embedded is available in 2 versions. Standard and Premium. Premium is necessary for multitouch support. Maybe you only got the standard version.